# Netbeans fails on existing SVN copy (LWC), checked out with external SVN client

Tags: svn, netbeans-7, svn-checkout

(*This question deals with particular problem — unable to work in Netbeans with existings LWCs. I know and understand, that the best (quickest) solution here is to checkout fresh copy out of repository, right in Netbeans. Please, don't put answers like that, as I'm aware of them. I'm seeking answer on how to work with existing LWCs, without need to checkout fresh copy, as this is not an option in my case*)

I've been working on my projects for past three years with Netbeans and TortoiseSVN separately. Now, I'm trying to use Subversion client bundled with Netbeans. And there's one glitch.

I have most recent version of repo in my LWC (local working copy). I have created new project in Netbeans, basing on existing sources, and pointed Netbeans to that LWC. It seems to intergrate quite well, as I can see all changes and perform (at least try to) some actions.

The thing is, that I can't find, where to specify repository URL, login and passwords and either these data is not stored in LWC or Netbeans can't read it properly.

For every Subversion action or operation, that requires access to remote repository, I'm getting an error window `Authentication failed`, like below:

[image: Netbeans Subversion Authentication Failed]

And there is no way I can fix this problem. As you can see, `Repository URL` is disabled and fields for login or password are missing at all. I've clicked-out entire Netbeans configuration, but either I'm looking in wrong place or there isn't any are, where I could specify URL, login and password.

I can click `Reply` in this window, but this is useless and pointless (one of *these* functions in Netbeans) as I can't provide corrected login credentials.

So, how can I use Netbeans on a LWC, that is not checked-out by itself, but was existing before IDE instalation and was checked out by external SVN client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something is wrong with your Netbeans instance. The correct "**Authentication failed"** dialog looks different and has all required fields.

[image: Netbeans_dialog]

Comment: Hm... That's strange... I installed newest stable 7.3 version. I'm quite hard to believe that they've published as stable, a version that contains such huge bug (prevents from re-using existing SVN LWCs and forces user to checkout again). In nightly, yes... but in official?